# How can I convert pseudocode to mergesort algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, pseudocode

I need to convert pseudocode into a merge sort algorithm that mirrors that pseudocode. I am new to pseudocode so I'm having trouble with this. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my algorithm? Please note that the arrays in the pseudocode are 1-indexed.

PSEUDOCODE:

```
MergeSort(A[1 .. n]):
   if n > 1
      m ← bn/2c
      MergeSort(A[1 .. m])
      MergeSort(A[m + 1 .. n])
      Merge(A[1 .. n], m)

Merge(A[1 .. n], m):
   i ← 1; j ← m + 1
   for k ← 1 to n
      if j > n
         B[k] ← A[i]; i ← i + 1
      else if i > m
         B[k] ← A[j]; j ← j + 1
      else if A[i] < A[ j]
         B[k] ← A[i]; i ← i + 1
      else
         B[k] ← A[j]; j ← j + 1
   for k ← 1 to n
      A[k] ← B[k]
```

MY CODE

```
def mergeSort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    if n > 1:
        m = n//2
        mergeSort(arr[:m])
        mergeSort(arr[m:])
        merge(arr, m)

def merge(arr, m):
    n = len(arr)
    i = 0
    j = m
    b = [0] * n
    
    for k in range(n):
        if j >= n:
            b[k] = arr[i]
            i += 1
        elif i > m-1:
            b[k] = arr[j]
            j += 1
        elif arr[i] < arr[j]:
            b[k] = arr[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            b[k] = arr[j]
            j += 1
    for k in range(n):
        arr[k] = b[k]
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: The array is not being sorted for some reason.

Comment: When I run it with the input // tester = [5, 1, 4, 2, 0, 19, 20, 3] // I get the result [0, 5, 1, 4, 2, 19, 20, 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that in the pseudo code version, the notation A[1..m] is supposed to mean a partition of the array, but **in-place**, not as a *new* array (slice): it is like a window on a part of the array, with its own indexing, but  not copied.

The translation to list slicing in Python does not reflect this. `arr[:m]` creates a new list, and so whatever `mergeSort(arr[:m])` does with that new list, it doesn't touch `arr` itself: all that work is for nothing, as it doesn't mutate `arr`, but a sliced copy of it, which we lose access to.

A solution is to not create slices, but to pass the start/end indices of the intended partition to the function call.

Here is the adapted code:

```
def mergeSort(arr):
    mergeSortRec(arr, 0, len(arr))

def mergeSortRec(arr, start, end):
    n = end - start
    if n > 1:
        m = start + n//2
        mergeSortRec(arr, start, m)
        mergeSortRec(arr, m, end)
        merge(arr, start, m, end)

def merge(arr, start, m, end):
    n = end - start
    i = start
    j = m
    b = [0] * n
    
    for k in range(n):
        if j >= end:
            b[k] = arr[i]
            i += 1
        elif i >= m:
            b[k] = arr[j]
            j += 1
        elif arr[i] < arr[j]:
            b[k] = arr[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            b[k] = arr[j]
            j += 1
    for k in range(n):
        arr[start + k] = b[k]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail and bonus python knowledge! Slava Ukraini!

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for me, however your operations are being applied in place, so you just need to call the function with the array to sort rather than getting the return value (which will always be None, because you provide no return in the function `mergeSort`)

```
arr = np.random.uniform(1, 10, 10)
print(arr)

[2.10748505 9.47408117 5.4620788  1.5585025  9.57387679 4.13719947
 1.28671255 4.150946   2.84044402 6.56294717]

mergeSort(arr)
print(arr)

[1.28671255 1.5585025  2.10748505 2.84044402 4.13719947 4.150946
 5.4620788  6.56294717 9.47408117 9.57387679]
```

Comment: I am calling it as such. I am unsure why it isn't reproducible. Thank you regardless.

Comment: If you add an example of how you are calling it in your question, I can help.

Comment: I am calling it as you do. mergeSort(arr) and then printing arr.
My test array tester = [5, 1, 4, 2, 0, 19, 20, 3] is yielding the result [0, 5, 1, 4, 2, 19, 20, 3]